# Cannot convert value of type '(data: CMAccelerometerData!, err: NSError!)

Tags: swift

Does this mean it should be unwrapped?

> Cannot convert value of type '(data: CMAccelerometerData!, err: NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'CMAccelerometerHandler' (aka '(Optional, Optional) -> ()')

Why is CMAccelerometerData not compatible with accelerometerUpdateHandler?

```
    // error
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(motionHandlingQueue, withHandler: accelerometerUpdateHandler())


    // snip

func accelerometerUpdateHandler() -> (data: CMAccelerometerData!, err: NSError!) -> Void {
    let idleThreshold = 0.1

    var log = [Double]()

    var samplingCountdown: Int = 0

    return { (data: CMAccelerometerData!, err: NSError!) -> Void in

        let _stable = abs(data.acceleration.x) < idleThreshold && abs(data.acceleration.y) < idleThreshold && data.acceleration.z < -0.75
```

Comment: Try `CMAccelerometerData?, err: NSError?)`

Comment: just use  `guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }`

Comment: try `motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(motionHandlingQueue, withHandler: accelerometerHandler)`

Comment: and `func accelerometerHandler(data: CMAccelerometerData?, error: NSError?) -> Void {
        let idleThreshold = 0.1
        var log = [Double]()
        var samplingCountdown: Int = 0
        guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
        let _stable = abs(data.acceleration.x) < idleThreshold && abs(data.acceleration.y) < idleThreshold && data.acceleration.z < -0.75
        // the rest of your code
    }`

Comment: Look-up the actual signature in the documentation of the class. This is the usual way to fix these kind of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define your accelerometerHandler as follow:

```
func accelerometerHandler(data: CMAccelerometerData?, error: NSError?) -> Void {
    guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
    let idleThreshold = 0.1
    var log = [Double]()
    var samplingCountdown: Int = 0
    let _stable = abs(data.acceleration.x) < idleThreshold && abs(data.acceleration.y) < idleThreshold && data.acceleration.z < -0.75
    // the rest of your code
}
```

---

when calling it:

```
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(motionHandlingQueue, withHandler: accelerometerHandler)
```

Comment: I noticed guard is in a different location compared with your original answer in the comments. Does it matter where it is?

Comment: It just need to be done before using the data. I usually place them before the rest of the code

Comment: Actually the error is always `nil` if data is not `nil` and vice versa so the `where` clause is redundant.

Comment: @vadian Are you saying I can write is like `guard let data  else { return }`?

Comment: @tymac Yes, you can (`guard let data = data else...`), but I'd add a line to print a potential error into the console.

Comment: Git it!!  `guard let data = data else {
            print("Acceleromter error")
            return
        }` Thanks!

Comment: oh I can use `error.code, error.domain` because the Accelerometer class has its own enum of error codes right? p.s. I noticed it has to be unwrapped. `(error!.code, error!.domain)`